# Javascript this.value behavior with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
 @Html.DropDownGroupListFor(m => m.CategoryID, Model.GroupedTypeOptions, new { @onchange = "javascript:OnDropDownChangeGetData(this.value)" })

 @Html.DropDownList("ddlMoreCategory", new SelectList(ViewBag.MoreCategoryList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Value", "Text"), new { @onchange = "javascript:OnDropDownChangeGetMoreData(this.value);" })
```

I have 2 dropdowns in my in my .cshtml file. onchange  of each of the dropdownlists i want to pass the selected value of each independent drop-down elements to a java-script function

The strange behavior i'm seeing is that, if for example DropDownGroupListFor onchange  event fires, its selected value is also passed to this.value of the second dropdown "DropDownList".

if this.value for DropDownGroupListFor is 4, then this.value for DropDownList also becomes 4. Is there away i can make this.value tied to a particular element?

Comment: post `OnDropDownChangeGetMoreData` and `OnDropDownChangeGetData` functions also..

Comment: Why don't you bind events individually by JavaScript selectElementById for "CategoryID" and "ddlMoreCategory" Ids.